# Move points and check specific start value, using classes python

Tags: python, oop, points

I need to be able to move points and check a specific point value. This is the code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self)
        #Here I want to move my points
```

Next class is a linestring. It must be able to handle *x* set of points

```
class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)
    def __getitem__(self):
         #Here I want to inspect the value of the specific
         # e.g. y value for the start point after it has been moved
```

I'm a bit unsure of how to get the `__getitem__` to work and whether it's in the right position. Should it be under `class Point`? Could this be done in another way?

Edited code;

```
from numpy import sqrt
import math

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, point):
        return math.hypot(self.x - point.x, self.y - point.y)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy

class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)

    def length(self):
        return sum(p1.dist(p2) for p1, p2 in zip(self.points[1:], self.points[:-1]))

    def move (self, x, y):
        for p in self.points:
            p.move(x, y)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.points[key]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need `__getitem` to do. Can you explain in clear English what you want the code to do?

Comment: Yes. I want the user of the program to be able to move inserted points and to inspect the new values. For example if we have a linestring of lin = LineString((2, 2), (3, 3)). I want to be able to use lin.move(1, 1) which will move the LineString points 1 step in x, y. Then it should be possible to return what the new values are. Such ass lin[0].y == 3 will be true.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is roughly what you want:

You don't seem to actually need a dictionary (for a line, I think a list makes more sense anyway). So the `Line` class is just a list of `Point`s, and it provides a move_all_points function to translate them all. Because `Line` subclasses a list, you get all the standard behaviour of lists for free:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Point({},{})>".format(self.x, self.y)
    def __str__(self):
        return(repr(self))
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        """Move the point by (dx, dy)."""
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

class Line(list):
    """A list of points that make up a line."""
    def move_all_points(self, dx, dy):
        for p in self:
            p.move(dx, dy)
```

So then you can use them as follows:

```
>>> p1, p2, p3 = Point(0, 0), Point(5, 0), Point(10, 10)

>>> my_line = Line((p1, p2, ))
>>> print my_line
[<Point(0,0)>, <Point(5,0)>]

>>> my_line.append(p3)
>>> print my_line
[<Point(0,0)>, <Point(5,0)>, <Point(10,10)>]

>>> p4 = Point(100,100)
>>> my_line.move_all_points(1, 1)
>>> print my_line
[<Point(1,1)>, <Point(6,1)>, <Point(11,11)>]

>>> my_line.append(p4)
>>> print my_line
[<Point(1,1)>, <Point(6,1)>, <Point(11,11)>, <Point(100,100)>]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code. However it did not do exactly what I wanted, most likely because I was unclear about it. I will post my finished code.